# Intelligent screen ruler for Linux with image edge detection (alternatiave for Microsoft PowerToys Ruler)

Tags: software-recommendation, screen, tools

So Microsoft has this [PowerToys screen ruler](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/microsoft-powertoys-could-soon-feature-a-ruler-for-measuring-objects-on-your-pc) with smart image edge detection to measure distance between objects on the screen. It looks really nice. I am wondering if there is such an app for Linux. I could not find anything so far. I only found very simple screen rulers like this [screenruler](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/screenruler.1.html).

It also seems like a relatively simple app to create using tools like [OpenCV](https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) to detect edges in an image and measure distance between them.

[image]